# Match parenthesised block using regular expressions in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to match the contents that belong between a certain `(` and its matching `)` as found by vim when using the motion `%`.

More specifically, I'm looking for a regex that looks like this hypothetical `/someKeyword (\{pair}\(.*\))\{pair}/`, if there were such modifiers as `\{pair}` that when applied to two exactly two characters in a regex, makes the second one only match if it's the matching bracket to the first one (`%`-wise).

The pattern I'm looking for should match the inner contents of the first bracket following `someKeyword` (n.b. the code that it should work on is always correctly bracketed), as in the examples:

For `someKeyword ("aaa")` the submatch will match `"aaa"`. 
Likewise `someKeyword ("aaa)")` will match `"aaa)"` and `someKeyword(("double-nested stuff"))` will match `("double-nested stuff")`

But also in cases like:

```
(
  someKeyword("xyz"))
```

where it should match `"xyz"`.

Is there any way to make use of vim's matching bracket functionality in regexes? And if not, what other solution might work to accomplish this?

Edit 1: the matched contents may span several lines.

Comment: spanning several lines is not a problem: replace `.` with `\_.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with vim regular expressions (as language that allows such nested constructs is not regular), but is possible with 'regular' expressions provided by perl (as well as by other languages I do not know enough to be sure) and perl can be used from inside vim. I don't like vim-perl bindings (because it is very limited), but if you know all cases that should work, then you could use recursion feature of perl regular expressions (requires newer perl, I have 5.12*):

```
perl VIM::Msg($+{"outer"}) if $curbuf->Get(3) =~ /someKeyword\((?'outer'(?'inner'"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|'(?:[^']|'')*'|[^()]*|\((?P>inner)*\))*)\)/
```

Note that if can avoid such regular expressions, you should do it (because you depend on re compiler too much), so I suggest to use vim motions directly:

```
let s:reply=""
function! SetReplyToKeywordArgs(...)
    let [sline, scol]=getpos("'[")[1:2]
    let [eline, ecol]=getpos("']")[1:2]
    let lchar=len(matchstr(getline(eline), '\%'.ecol.'c.'))
    if lchar>1
        let ecol+=lchar-1
    endif
    let text=[]
    let ellcol=col([eline, '$'])
    let slinestr=getline(sline)
    if sline==eline
        if ecol>=ellcol
            call extend(text, [slinestr[(scol-1):], ""])
        else
            call add(text, slinestr[(scol-1):(ecol-1)])
        endif
    else
        call add(text, slinestr[(scol-1):])
        let elinestr=getline(eline)
        if (eline-sline)>1
            call extend(text, getline(sline+1, eline-1))
        endif
        if ecol<ellcol
            call add(text, elinestr[:(ecol-1)])
        else
            call extend(text, [elinestr, ""])
        endif
    endif
    let s:reply=join(text, "\n")
endfunction
function! GetKeywordArgs()
    let winview=winsaveview()
    keepjumps call search('someKeyword', 'e')
    setlocal operatorfunc=SetReplyToKeywordArgs
    keepjumps normal! f(g@i(
    call winrestview(winview)
    return s:reply
endfunction
```

You can use something like

```
let savedureg=@"
let saved0reg=@0
keepjumps normal! f(yi(
let s:reply=@"
let @"=savedureg
let @0=saved0reg
```

instead of operatorfunc to save and restore registers, but the above code leaves all registers and marks untouched, what I can't guarantee with saved* stuff. It also guarantees that if you remove `join()` around `text`, you will save information about the location of NULLs (if you care about them, of course). It is not possible with registers variant.

Answer (score 4):

Most regex dialects can't do this. It is possible with the .NET implementation (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx)), but very, very ugly and should not be used in my opinion.

Comment: +1. And, if your regex dialect can do this, it is no longer a regular expression in the strict mathematical sense...

Comment: @Aasmund: Well, most useful regular expressions aren't =)

Answer (score 1):

As Jens told, this cannot be done with Vim regular expressions.

However if you want to do some special processing you can possibly do the following:

- Find opening parentheses that interest you and then run a macro that will insert some character (let's say `^@`) after the opening parenthese and before the closing parenthese using the `%` binding.
- Then modify the regex accordingly.

Comment: that's a bit ugly, it actually modifies the state of my file instead of just remembering the positions that i'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this quite easily with a macro.  You would search for the keyword with a regexp and then search for the start of the text, then the end of it, then you can undertake what ever action that you want.

E.g. to yank the required text:

```
qa/somekeyword\s*
/(
lvh%hyq
```

Now whenever you use the macro with `@a` you would yank the next bit of text that you are interested in.

Comment: I would use text objects and visual mode. `qq/keyword\s*<cr>\(<cr>vi(q`

Answer (score 0):

A regex way to highlight code blocks is as follow for `{}` nested curly brackets:

`/{[A-Za-z \n]\+\(\(\({[A-Za-z \n]\+\)\{3}\([A-Za-z \n]\+}\)\{3}\)\+[A-Za-z \n]\+\)\+}`

for `()` simple nested parentheses:

`/([A-Za-z \n]\+\(\(\(([A-Za-z \n]\+\)\{3}\([A-Za-z \n]\+)\)\{3}\)\+[A-Za-z \n]\+\)\+)`

Where `\{3}...\{3}` must be replace for desired nesting level.

You also can modify `[A-Za-z \n]\+` groups to increase characters matching.

An so on an so forth.

Best regards!