# match closing parenthesis in vim search and replace

Tags: regex, vim

In vim in normal mode I can move to a closing parenthesis using %. Is there an equivalent to that which I can use in a search and replace command? Assuming I have some latex code from which I want to remove the italics. In a simple scenario something like `:%s/{\\it \(.*\)}/\1/gc` would do the job, but in practice this will stop at the first closing curly brace which in all probability closes something else, as I might have `{\it some text in italics {\bf and some in bold also} ...possibly so many other commands with curly braces... and finally my closing curly brace:}`.

Comment: Have you checked [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5146698/3832970)?

Comment: @stribizhev No, I hadn't seen that, thanks. Seems like the long term answer is to learn perl and the short term solution is to write a small macro and use search, which in fact shouldn't be much slower than automatic search and replace with the `confirm` switch.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but Tim Pope's [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) might still make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you mean by "write a small macro and use search", but you can use normal mode commands with the `normal` command, e.g.:

```
:g|{\\it|normal /{\\it^M%mm%5x`mx
```

`:g` will trigger on every line that matches the pattern *`{\it`*, and for each match, it runs the normal mode commands `/{\\it` to jump to the right place in the line, `%` to get to the closing brace, `mm` to put a mark at the closing one, `%` to jump back to the opening one, `5x` to delete the opening command, then `m to jump back to the mark, and `x` to remove the closing one.

What this won't handle is several `{\it` openings on one line. (But you could just run it again). Quicker than learning Perl.