# replace with maching braces

Tags: regex, vim, greedy, regex-greedy

How to search and replace by matching braces?

eg i/p:

```
{\sc This is {very} hard for {me} to} code. this is just an {example}
```

Required o/p:

```
This is {very} hard for {me} to
```

I used this code. but failed to get that

```
%s/{\\sc\s*\([^}]*\)}/\1/gec
```

Comment: Perhaps, related: [Match parenthesised block using regular expressions in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139300/match-parenthesised-block-using-regular-expressions-in-vim). I think you need to use PCRE regex for this.

Comment: You can use: `:%!grep -m1 -oP '{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*}' | head -1`

Comment: @hek2mgl, I am a beginner in vim. could you please explain what each char means.

Comment: can this be use in my pattern like : %s/%!grep -m1 -oP '{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*}'//gec

Comment: @SamjithDasan Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php . It's the PHP documentation but it is good explained there. The syntax is the same as `grep -P` (*perl compatible regexes*)

Comment: thanks for the link. is  there any way to apply this search pattern like %s/../../gec.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex match brackets with 2 nested levels:

`:%s/.*\({.[A-Za-z ]\+\({.[A-Za-z ]\+}.\{-}[A-Za-z ]\)\+}\).*/\1`

Works for several examples like:

> **input 1**  {\sc This is {very} hard for {me} to} code. this is just an {example}···
>
> **output 1** {\sc This is {very} hard for {me} to}
>
> **input 2**    bla blah blah {\sc This is {very} hard {for}... {me} to} code. this is just an {e    xample}···
>
> **output 2**  {\sc This is {very} hard {for}... {me} to}

And another more general way to highlight nested brackets is:

`/{[A-Za-z \n]\+\(\(\({[A-Za-z \n]\+\)\{3}\([A-Za-z \n]\+}\)\{3}\)\+[A-Za-z \n]\+\)\+}`

Where `\{3}...\{3}` must be replace for desired nesting level.