# Can Recursive Regularization be Used in vim?

Tags: regex, perl, vim

Match the following text

```
{
class innerC{
}
}
```

I use below in perl

```
(\{[^{}]*(?1)*[^{}]*\})
```

But it doesn't work in vim.Does vim not support Recursive regular?How to achieve the above matching in vim

Comment: You would need a multiline regex for this. Maybe this vim wike page [Search across multiple lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines) will help you.

Comment: Oh and it seems in vim regexes you need to write `{` to match `{`, i.e. `/{\{1}\n\a*` matches exactly 1 `{`.

Comment: I only get `/\({\{1}\n[^{}]*{\n\}*\n}\)/` to match, but that doesn't recurse. Are you sure the syntax `?1` is correct?

Comment: @StefanBecker it works in perl

Comment: Well, vim is not Perl, and I gather it uses its own regex engine, not even PCRE. Maybe this SO question [Match parenthesised block using regular expressions in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139300/match-parenthesised-block-using-regular-expressions-in-vim) helps?

Comment: @StefanBecker Thank you for your help. Judging from the answer, it seems very difficult to Recursive in vim.

Comment: I guess you should answer yourself and accept the answer.

Comment: @StefanBecker You have spent a lot of energy and time on this.You can answer and I will adopt you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately vim is not Perl, and I gather it uses its own regex engine, not even PCRE.

According to this SO question [Match parenthesised block using regular expressions in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139300/match-parenthesised-block-using-regular-expressions-in-vim) the vim regex engine doesn't support recursive regexes.